# An inequality in the Lectures on differential geometry by Schoen and Yau, how to prove $\|u\|_p \leqslant C \sqrt{p}\|\nabla u\|_2$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

In fact, it's in the first section of chapter5, it's in the proof of the trudinger inequality.

Let $D$ be a unit disk, set $v \in C_0^1(D)$, the authors wrote $$
\begin{aligned}
&v(x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_D \nabla v(y) \cdot \frac{x-y}{|x-y|^2} d y,\\
&|v(x)| \leqslant \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_D|\nabla v(y)| \cdot \frac{d y}{|x-y|} .
\end{aligned}
$$
then they wrote the term in the integral as
$$
\left(|\nabla v|^2|x-y|^{-q}\right)^{1 / p} \cdot|x-y|^{-q / 2} \cdot|\nabla v|^{1-2 / p}
$$
and used holder inequality to get
$$
\begin{aligned}
|v(x)| \leqslant & \frac{1}{2 \pi}\left(\int_D|\nabla v(y)|^2|x-y|^{-q} d y\right)^{1 / p} \\
& \cdot\left(\int_D|x-y|^{-q} d y\right)^{1 / 2}\left(\int_D|\nabla v|^2 d y\right)^{1 / 2-1 / p}
\end{aligned}
$$
here $q=\frac{2 p}{p+2}<2$, and note that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_D|x-y|^{-q} d y & =\int_{|x-y|<1}|y|^{-q} d y \leqslant \int_{|y|<2}|y|^{-q} d y \\
& =2 \pi \int_0^2 r^{1-q} d r=2^{1-q} \pi(p+2),
\end{aligned}
$$
then they got
$$
\begin{gathered}
\int_D|\nabla v|^p d x \leqslant c_1(p+2)^{\frac{p}{2}+1}\left(\int_D|\nabla v|^2 d x\right)^{p / 2}, \\
\left(\int_D|\nabla v|^p d x\right)^{1 / p} \leqslant c_2 \sqrt{p}\left(\int_D|v|^2 d x\right)^{1 / 2},
\end{gathered}
$$
this is very confusing, I thought about this for several days but got no clue, could someone give me some hints?

Comment: At which step do you have problems to understand?

Comment: Actually, I don't even know how they get $\int_D|\nabla v|^p d x \leqslant c_1(p+2)^{\frac{p}{2}+1}\left(\int_D|\nabla v|^2 d x\right)^{p / 2}$.